# How to remove custom action/link from list item menu?

Tags: 2013, list, custom-list, custom-actions, list-form

In SharePoint 2013, using Designer 2013, I created a custom action for a list while creating a new form for it.

[image: Create New List Form - Create link in List Item Menu and Ribbon]

Then I scrapped the new form. I actually did this twice.

Now, in the list's item menu, the custom actions show up, but I don't want them to. They don't correlate to anything.

[image: List Item Menu with custom Authorize action(s)]

How do I **remove** them?

I want to truly remove them. I've seen forum chatter across the interwebs about hiding list actions with various methods like JavaScript, but this just seems silly to me. I'm in the middle of tinkering with custom forms and actions, etc. for this list. While I'm definitely going to be more careful about creating custom actions, it's bound to happen again that I'll create a custom action for testing/experimenting while I try to perfect this list. So it would make so much more sense to just know how to actually delete custom actions altogether. Beyond that, understanding how to heal the wound seems infinitely more valuable to me than having to find and rely on Band Aids. In other words, I'm wholly unimpressed and uninterested in any answers that explain how to hide. Instructions for removal are the only thing I'm interested in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Open site in SharePoint Designer
2. From left navigation choose Lists and Libraries
3. Open the list in question
4. Now from right pane - Look under "Custom Actions"
5. Select the action to delete
6. Use Ribbon "Delete" button OR press `Delete` key

[image]